# Backslash is automatically added after saving on README.md

Tags: visual-studio-code, readme

I am editing our README.md. I noticed that on save, it adds \ (backslash) on save.

```
[:heavy_check_mark: JUMP TO](jump-to-sample)
```

turns to this after saving:

```
[:heavy\_check\_mark: JUMP TO](jump-to-sample)
```

Even if I remove the backslash, it will still return whenever I save the file. I'm using current version of VS code

Is there a way to stop VS code in adding backslashes automatically?

**EDIT**: Figured it out. It was because of the extension **Markdown All in One**. On disable, no more backlash is added upon saving.